# A class import is missing in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why laravel can't load general.php in helpers folder ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJDIp.png)

> composer.json

```
"files":[
        "app/Helpers/General.php"
    ],
```

> app.php

```
'providers' => [
 ...
  App\Providers\GeneralServiceProvider::class,
 ],

 'aliases'=> [
 ...
 'General'=> 'App\Helpers\General::class',
 ]
```

> GeneralServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GeneralServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    require_once app_path() . '/Helpers/General.php';
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is `General` a class or a file with functions in it?

Comment: why do you need this class loaded in this special way? ... every thing in `app` is already loaded into the `App` namespace by the PSR4 autoloading

Comment: I need the file because it has a function inside sir @Jerodev

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line in `app.php`,

```
'General' => 'App\Helpers\General::class',
```

To this.

```
'General' => App\Helpers\General::class,
```

See the difference?

Comment: This would be the case if `General` is a facade, which is not indicated by OP.